# Command not found, no root permission

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I am facing this issue,

```
make: nvcc: Command not found
Makefile:134: recipe for target 'objs/core_nlmkernel.o' failed
make: *** [objs/core_nlmkernel.o] Error 127
```

I don't have root permissions for this school machine, so I can't edit the related paths in the bashrc file. Is there another solution for solving this problem?

Is it possible to edit the makefile to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use command nvcc with full path.
if command is there in your home folder you can call like /home/your-folder/command in makefile.
hope this helps.